# Se cierra mi modal cuando escribo en un v-text-field, que es lo que pasa?

Tags: vue.js

Tengo un modal que se abre para editar un documento que tengo en firestore, este el modal:

```
<v-flex>
        <span v-if="state.currentPage == 'list'">
          <span>My Themes</span>
          <v-btn color="success" @click="changeState()">New Theme</v-btn>
          <listTheme />
        </span>

        <span v-if="state.currentPage != 'list'">
          <v-btn color="default" @click="changeState()">Cancel</v-btn>
          <v-btn color="success" @click="addTheme(typeTheme), changeState()">
            Create
          </v-btn>
          <v-col cols="2">
            <v-select
              v-model="typeTheme.type"
              :items="getTypesCategories.typeOptions"
              item-value="label"
              item-text="label"
              label="Themes"
            />
            <v-text-field
              v-model="typeTheme.title"
              color="success"
              placeholder="Title"
            />
            <v-text-field
              v-model="typeTheme.description"
              color="success"
              placeholder="Description"
            />
          </v-col>
        </span>
      </v-flex>
```

estoy usando vuex, por lo tanto tengo este metodo para abrir o cerrar el modal

```
methods: {
    changeState() {
      this.state.currentPage =
        this.state.currentPage == 'list' ? 'create' : 'list';
    },
  }
```

ocurre algo raro en esta parte del modal:

```
<v-text-field
                  v-model="typeTheme.title"
                  color="success"
                  placeholder="Title"
                />
```

cuando escribo cualquier cosa en el v-text-field se cierra mi modal, que pasa?

solo se cierra en ese text field, en el segundo text field todo normal.

Answer (score 1):

¿por qué no usas los v-if para hacer aparecer el modal?.
Ejemplo:

```
<div v-if="modalVisible" @close="closeModal">resto del modal</div>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
          return {
            modalVisible: false
          };
        },

        methods: {
          openModal() {
            this.modalVisible = true;
          },

          closeModal() {
            this.modalVisible = false;
          }
        } 
    }
</script>
```

Y en la sección del modal agregas esto en el botón de cierre:

```
@click.stop="close"
```

En el methods del modal agregas esto:

```
methods: {

  close() {
    this.$emit('close');
  },
}
```

Acabo de resaltar que lo estoy haciendo así como si el modal estuviera en otra parte, por lo cual tienes que importarlo.

Comment: de igual manera se cierra con el text-field